# How does a country block/censor an encrypted website (HTTPS)?

Tags: tls, censorship

Given that Site *X* uses HTTPS, how can it be blocked by a country?

My browser reads: 128-bit encryption | ECDHE_RSA as key exchange.

I say it's blocked since when I use Tor, it works fine.

One important thing to point out is that it's not blocked in the typical sense we are used to see, which clearly shows a page that says it's blocked, instead, site *X* is blocked in a way that my browser just doesn't load the page and displays the error:

> This webpage is not available, Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

for the HTTPS version, and that regular "page is blocked" page when requesting the HTTP version.

Note that **no other HTTPS sites are blocked**! Just this one! I assume this is evidence that excludes port blocking and protocol blocking. However, it leaves DPI; but there are other HTTP-blocked websites which have the HTTPS version still working! If they can DPI-block site *X*, why can't they block the other HTTPS sites the same way?

Comment: You might get a more precise answer when you would say which country you are from. Web censorship is implemented differently in different countries.

Comment: I assume you are also using another browser when you connect via Tor network. In this case it might actually be an error in your browser. Have you tested it in other browser or another device?

Comment: Nope, I torified Chrome in my PC (anonymity is not a concern with this site, only censorship bypass is) so it works with Tor ON, and doesn't with Tor OFF, and I also tested it on Android (Next Browser)

Comment: They will block it via IP and domain name. You can use it using TOR since different IP will be serving the page for you which won't be blacklisted.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

TL;DR: TLS only secures the content of a message. Not the metadata.

When communicating over the clear net, it's important to remember that there are some portions of a given communication that cannot be secured using standard technologies. Unless you use something like TOR, your ISP will be able to determine who you're talking to even if you're using TLS.

To use an analogy, imagine sending an envelope via the postal service. The contents of the envelope are completely inaccessible to anyone other than the recipient. Even if a postman were to somehow view the contents, they wouldn't be able to comprehend it (Perhaps you ran it through a Caesar cipher first? Hehe).

However, in order to have the postal service send it to the correct address, the outside of the envelope must be marked with a plainly readable representation of the destination address. If the postal service didn't want anyone to be able to send letters to "Joe Schmoe, 123 Fake street," then they could just not deliver any letters with that address.

Since the postal service can't read the contents of the message, they have no way to identify the intent of the letter. The only information that they have is the fact that the intended recipient is Joe Schmoe. They can't screen only the letters that they deem to be malicious; it's all or nothing.

Similarly, the IP protocol (the routing protocol that TCP runs on top of) has plainly marked "sender" and "receiver" fields. TLS cannot encrypt this for two reasons:

- TLS runs on top of TCP/IP, and thus cannot modify parts of the packets that belong to those protocols.
- If the IP section was encrypted, then the carrier service (ISP routers) would not be able to identify where the packets need to go to.

The firewall that your ISP or country is forcing all of your traffic through cannot inspect TLS traffic. They only know the metadata supplied by the TCP/IP protocol. They have also deemed that the site you want to access is more bad than good, so they drop all of the traffic to and from the site regardless of the contents.

There is a method to secure even the metadata of online communications, but it is slow and not very scalable. TOR hidden services are one attempt at implementing this. Of course, hidden services only work within the TOR network, which can only be accessed by first connecting to a machine over the clear net. This means that the ISP or firewall still knows that you're proxying your data through the onion. No matter how you try, you will always leak *some* metadata. If they wanted to, they could reset all connections to TOR nodes in addition to the site they're currently blocking.

If you are trying to establish a direct connection to a specific IP through a firewall, and the firewall has explicit rules to kill any traffic to or from that given IP, then connecting to that IP directly will always be fruitless. You will have to connect to it indirectly, either through TOR, a VPN, or some other proxy service.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  To refresh your memory: the question was, how are they blocking my connection?  I don't see an answer here. (Tangentially, the answer is pretty obvious: DNS blocking or packet inspection.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I made the answer abundantly clear. While TLS is securing content of the traffic to and from the site, the TCP/IP transport layers are still open to inspection. Any firewalls that the OP's connection passes through can easily discard any packets sent to or from an undesirable IP.

Comment: That wasn't clear to me.  I suggest editing your answer to state the answer to the question explicitly.  One way would be to start with the answer to the question, and then elaborate on the details.

Comment: There's a [Tor and HTTPS article](https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https) from EFF explaining what gets leaked when using HTTPS

Comment: But I also know some proxies that can bypass restrictions, for example at high school they blocked most web proxies but they couldn't block ones starting with https and I thought it was because https:// encrypts the headers? I guess maybe it only encrypts some.

Comment: A lot of firewalls employed by places such as high schools often rely on scanning the traffic for keywords. If the traffic is over TLS, then the firewall can't scan for keywords. At my high school, the only thing our filter did was check the hostname of sites. This defeated your HTTPS workaround, but you could still DNS the url and connect using the IP. I believe that most firewalls put in place by schools are there to help increase productivity, not to censor content. That's why they're hilariously easy to work around.

Comment: @Celeritas it does encrypt the headers. It doesn't encrypt the destination address. (Think about it - if the destination address was encrypted, how would it know where to send your packets?). I don't know why your school wouldn't block https proxies, but it might have to do with poor-quality admins.

Comment: @immibis because that would involve blocking ALL https traffic. Its not possible to inspect https traffic without breaking the encryption. Without doing so, you cannot tell if the request is a proxy request or a standard one.

Comment: @Aron as has been already stated many times, https does not hide the IP address of the server. If awesomeproxy.com has an IP address of 1.2.3.4, (and there's no other important site on 1.2.3.4, which is likely to be the case) then it's easy to block all traffic to and from 1.2.3.4.

Comment: @immibis you need to identify the https server AS a proxy. You need to know that that ip runs a proxy. That IS hard.

Comment: @Aron It isn't that hard, there are tons of url-lists, which divide almost any publicly used address into categories like commercial, malware, proxy... It is employed in most companies, so a school could easily do it. They could use whitelisting and it would be absolute bullet-proof, unless you can host a proxy on some whitelisted domain...

Comment: @Aron you just need to bribe one student to tell you the IP. But also, most proxies that students are likely to use will also run a webserver that says they're a proxy - just connect to the IP, see proxy setup instructions, blacklist the IP.

Comment: @immibis Tell me how that tactic works to stop weed from being sold in schools.

Comment: @Aron I never said anything about weed, only proxy servers.

Comment: @immibis I am saying that schools typically find it hard enough to stop students doing worst things using black lists. But maintaining a global list of https proxies is hard. It takes a huge amount of resources to check each and every server the students go to. Paying off informants works so well for the police that no crime exists. Black listing by its very nature is an arms race, and there are vastly more students than there are administrators.

Comment: @Falco also, some legitimate sites can be used as proxies. One that I frequently used in my school was Google translate, which provides a handy service to translate webpages. If you enter a url, Google translate will proxy the url to translate the site. For example https://example.com becomes https://24znitetvn2qmcz4udhtbwpaqe-ac5fdsxevxq4s5y-example-com.translate.goog/ . Try blocking that!

Comment: @KartikSoneji that is the beauty of whitelisting. You only whitelist certain websites which don't provide such functionality. Many lists used by companies usually include google translate in the "possbile proxy functionality" tag.

Comment: @Falco Yes, but that disables Google Translate, which is very useful for a school (assuming multiple languages are taught). Also, there is no way of knowing which services can be used as a proxy without constant through testing, and that can become quite labour intensive.

Comment: @KartikSoneji and this is why it's a business model to provide customers with a curated whitelist of services, where customers pay a monthly fee and the provider makes sure the pages in the whitelist cannot be used to circumvent filters.

Comment: @KartikSoneji Easy. `*.translate.goog` should be blocked, and `translate.google.com` should not.

Answer (score 34):

Many government web filters are implemented through DNS filtering.

In order to connect to `https://www.example.com`, your browser first connects to the DNS server of your internet service provider and asks for the IP address of `www.example.com`. It then builds an encrypted connection to the IP it gets. So the government instructs the ISPs to configure their DNS servers to return no or a fake IP address for the websites they want to block.

To test this, you could configure your network settings to use a different DNS server, like Google's `8.8.8.8`. How to do this depends on your operating system, but a guide should be easy to find.

Another method of web filtering is by IP address itself. The ISPs just configure their firewalls to blocks all traffic to the IP address of `example.com`. Such a filter is harder to circumvent than a DNS filter, but causes a lot more collateral damage. Large web hosters often host thousands or even millions of completely unrelated websites on the same IP address. When ISPs block by IP, they can't block a specific site without also blocking all the others which share the IP.

Comment: Nope, that's impossible in my case. I'm using encrypted DNS. Sorry for not providing that info earlier.

Comment: @Mars Encrypted DNS doesn't do much when the DNS server itself is compromised by censorship.

Comment: It's not. The DNS is clean, and I've also just tested another 5 public DNS (Google (2), OpenDNS, Swiss Foundation, and Local ISP)

Comment: Well, that would hint at IP blocking being applied. Have you tried a simple proxy outside your country yet? That could get you a further understanding of what's going on...

Comment: Don't forget that the addresses of those public DNS servers may also be redirected to a rogue DNS server working for your country. Make sure you test them through Tor too, to cross-validate the results, or you won't be able to assess the correctness of the responses you're getting.

Answer (score 20):

When you connect to an HTTPS website, the hostname of the website you are connecting to is transmitted over the network *in cleartext* as part of the [TLS handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Basic_TLS_handshake).  The server's [certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Certificates_and_web_site_security) always contains the hostname, because that's how the server *authenticates* itself to the client: "I am the server that is authorized to serve content for `www.foo.example`, according to Jim-Bob's Bait Shop and Certificate Authority."  Modern browsers<sup>1</sup> also send the hostname in cleartext from the *client* to the *server*, in the "[Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)" message which makes it possible to host many HTTPS websites on one IPv4 address.

This is necessary because of the way the math of setting up a secure channel works.  Basically, the server has to make a cryptographically unforgeable assertion of its  hostname (and some other stuff, most importantly its "public key"), in cleartext, before the process of "key agreement" begins, or else the client cannot be sure that there is no [man in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) intercepting communications.

But the downside is, a "deep packet inspection" firewall can learn that you are trying to connect to a specific website, and block access (e.g. by forging TCP RST packets) even though it couldn't have eavesdropped on the *content* of your communications with that site, and even if you never reveal the hostname of the site you want to communicate with in any other way.

<sup>1</sup> in this case, "everything you are likely to encounter nowadays, with the glaring exceptions of IE on Windows XP, and the stock Android browser prior to 3.0; unfortunately, both of those are more common than we'd like".

Answer (score 4):

HTTPS does not and cannot hide the IP and hostname of a website or the fact that you're connecting to it. It only encrypts the traffic sent over that connection *once it is established*.

Given that, it is trivial for someone controlling the line to terminate any connections for a particular site. What HTTPS (hopefully) prevents them from doing is monitoring or modifying the information exchanged with the site, but the fact that you're connecting to it is always visible.

Answer (score 2):

Institutions and companies [eg. hotspot providers] generally deal with this in two ways:

- Instructing DNS servers to point at other IPs: this is a weak obstacle, since technically savvy users can easily change their DNS service, and used when it's not really important to block a site. I believe this is what, for example, the Italian government does: the national ISPs are asked to change their DNS servers so that requests to banned site are instead redirected to a government-hosted page.
- Blocking connections on an IP basis, rather than on a domain basis: this normally requires a transparent proxy (especially used by hotspot providers and such) or a firewall with deep packet inspection (eg. the Chinese firewall). To prevent the user from connecting to banned IPs, a few techniques are then used - among them, injecting TCP reset packets, redirecting packets, or simply dropping them.

Comment: > Blocking connections on an IP basis, rather than on a domain basis: this normally requires a transparent proxy (hence why this is generally used by hotspot providers and such) which drops packets sent to banned IPs, or otherwise stops connections (eg. the Chinese firewall injects TCP reset packets). Rubbish. You don't need proxies or packet inspection or any L4 stuff if all you want to do is block access to IP addresses. Simple L3 routing techniques (BGP etc.) is all you need.... and you can apply it at whatever level you want ... ISP level, per-subscriber etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the target site itself is preventing you from accessing it from the source IP range in question.

I know firsthand of many large organisations who block countries not for any other reason than to minimise exposure to hackers coming from that region.

Comment: Nope. It's The Pirate Bay..

Comment: If it's TPB, then you might as well just use it on TOR. It's not exactly a heavy bandwidth user, and it can even be accessed as a hidden service (http://uj3wazyk5u4hnvtk.onion/). They're likely just killing all traffic to the known IP addresses for TPB.

Comment: I can access it already. I'm more interested in knowing HOW they can block it since it uses SSL! That's why I didn't mention the site name, it's irrelevant knowledge-wise

Comment: @Mars Some sites are hosted from dynamic IPs, but i don't think TPB is.

Answer (score 0):

My ISP can block access to some site even with DOH applied.
Without DOH, while accessing blocked site browser while redirect to ISP page.
With DOH when i access browser says "SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN".
So i open cerificate button and this certificate is belong to ISP. Thats mean ISP block site via injecting ssl cert